# Density in Sobolev Space

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I was told that in one dimension, if we consider a half open interval (a,b] then the space $C_{c}^{\infty}((a,b])$ is dense in $\tilde{H}^{1}((a,b)):=\{u\in H^{1}((a,b))\,|\,u(a)=0\}$. I am not sure how to show this.

I am familiar with density theorems for $H^{1}$ and $H^{1}_{0}$ but I am not sure how to progress when you have a mix between these two spaces. Can anyone offer a suggestion of how to consider this problem?

Comment: Remark that a compact subset of $(a,b]$ can contain $b$ but will always be away from $a$ (i.e. it is included in $(c,b]$ for some $c>a$) and so compactly supported functions of this space are $0$ in $a$ but also in a neighborhood of $a$, while they can take any value in $b$.

Comment: I am aware of this behaviour for $C^{\infty}_{c}((a,b])$ however I am unsure how to use the existing density theorems for $H^{1}$ and $H^{1}_{0}$ to conclude that $\overline{C_{c}^{\infty}((a,b])}^{H^{1}}=\tilde{H}^{1}((a,b))$. Is it simply just an extension of the fact that $\overline{C_{c}^{\infty}((a,b))}^{H^{1}}=H^{1}_{0}((a,b))$?

Comment: I posted a potential answer below, to aid in what I am trying to explain here.

Answer (score 0):

Since $C_{c}^{\infty}((a,b))\subseteq C_{c}^{\infty}((a,b])\subseteq C^{\infty}([a,b])$ then using the fact that $\overline{C_{c}^{\infty}((a,b))}^{H^{1}}=H^{1}_{0}((a,b))$ and $\overline{C^{\infty}([a,b])}^{H^{1}}=H^{1}((a,b))$ we have that $\overline{C_{c}^{\infty}((a,b])}^{H^{1}}=\tilde{H}^{1}((a,b))$.